# "Света нет" - сказал Ахмед(, /.) работы(,) соответственно(,) тоже нет

Tags: пунктуация

Какие знаки нужны в следующем фрагменте текста?

***"Света нет" - сказал Ахмед(,/.) работы(,) соответственно(,) тоже нет.***

Answer (score 2):

Не совсем понятно, что именно Вас интересует. Если Вас интересуют запятые перед и после "соответственно", то указанные запятые нужны, так как это вводное слово. 
Обратите внимание: перед тире также необходима запятая.

Comment: Спасибо! А если предложение образовать так, то запятая перед тире нужна? "Света нет" — сказал Ахмед, тем самым освободив подчинённых от работы.

Comment: Запятая перед тире в любом случае необходима. Здесь прямая речь, которая стоит перед вводящими ее словами автора. В этом случае после прямой речи ставится запятая и тире.

Comment: Понятно. Большое спасибо. :)

Answer (score 2):

"Света нет, - сказал Ахмед, -  и работы, соответственно, тоже нет".

Схема: П - А - П, слова автора внутри прямой речи.